# Drag and Drop in C#?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

How to Implement Drag and Drop Between my Program and Explorer
ya windows application only

Comment: What is "Program" ? Windows app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you're using WinForms, it's actually very straightforward. See these two articles to get you started:

- [Drag and Drop files from Windows Explorer to Windows Form](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dragdrop.aspx)
- [Drag and Drop Text Files from Windows Explorer to your Windows Form Application](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=192&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

And just in case you're using WPF, [this tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html) and [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316900/dragndrop-one-or-more-mails-from-outlook-to-c-wpf-application) should help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good article on CodeProject about how to do this:

> This sample project lists a folder
>   full of files, and lets you drag and
>   drop them into Explorer. You can also
>   drag from Explorer into the sample,
>   and you can use the Shift and Ctrl
>   keys to modify the action, just like
>   in Explorer.

[Drag and drop, cut/copy and paste files with Windows Explorer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/Explorer_Drag_Drop.aspx)

> To start a drag operation into
>   Explorer, we implement the `ItemDrag`
>   event from the `Listview`, which gets
>   called after you drag an item more
>   than a few pixels. We simply call
>   `DoDragDrop` passing the files to be
>   dragged wrapped in a `DataObject`. You
>   don't really need to understand
>   `DataObject` - it implements the
>   `IDataObject` interface used in the
>   communication.

Answer (score 1):

Add this on the Drag enter event (this will change the cursor type when you are dragging a file)

```
 private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // If file is dragged, show cursor "Drop allowed"
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }
```

Then on the DragDrop event you need to handle what do ou want to do.
And also set the AllowDrop property to true