# Dragging objects from one application to another

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two small applications: an image file explorer, and an image viewer.

The explorer uses a standard tree view to display contents from the file system.
The viewer supports drag and drop to load files.

I want to drag a file entry from my explorer into my viewer and have it load the image.
Each node in the explorer holds a FileInfo object in its tag if I need to access specific info.

Is this possible?

Note: I can build the viewer directly into the explorer, but I wanted to see whether I can drag objects both in and out of an application.

Comment: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669204/drag-and-drop

Comment: I couldn't find something that would appear to allow me to drag data from one of my applications into another application. Most of them seem to talk about dragging data from windows explorer or outlook into a custom app. I'm thinking I would have to use DragLeave at some point, but not really sure how to actually drag say the contents of a tree node out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some basic code to take data from your custom app...

```
DataObject d = new DataObject(); 
d.SetData(DataFormats.Serializable, myObject); 
myForm.DoDragDrop(d, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

You typically start by identifying the source of your drag, UIElement or ContentElement and create a handler for the MouseMove event.  That is where the above code should go.

On your drop target, you also identify the element, set AllowDrop to true, and implement the Drop event handler.  Take a look at [Drag and Drop Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx) which should be very helpful.